# libGDX contact script not working

Tags: libgdx

This contact script is not being called when any 2 bodies come into contact with each other. I have tried simply calling the method whenever any object bodies come into contact but that does not work either.

```
world.setContactListener(new ContactListener() {

        @Override
        public void beginContact(Contact contact) {
            Fixture f1 = contact.getFixtureA();
            Fixture f2 = contact.getFixtureB();

            Body b1 = f1.getBody();
            Body b2 = f2.getBody();

            if((b1.getUserData() == "player" && b2.getUserData() == "Enemy") || (b1.getUserData() == "player" && b2.getUserData() == "Enemy"))  {
                player.death();
                hud.death();
        }
        }

        @Override
        public void endContact(Contact contact) {

        }

        @Override
        public void preSolve(Contact contact, Manifold oldManifold) {

        }

        @Override
        public void postSolve(Contact contact, ContactImpulse impulse) {

        }
    });
```

Comment: In your sample code, both of your conditionals use b1 for player. Shouldn't it be b1 in one and b2 in the other.

Answer (score 0):

1. Make sure that the player and enemy bodies are defined as *Dynamic Body*.
2. Check your collision filtering.
3. Check if the body is active.
4. Also check if you properly set the userdata of each body.